# Sorting DataStream using Apache Flink

Tags: sorting, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am learning Flink and I started with a simple word count using DataStream. To enhance the processing I filtered the output to show only the results with 3 or more words found.

```
    DataStream<Tuple2<String, Integer>> dataStream = env
            .socketTextStream("localhost", 9000)
            .flatMap(new Splitter())
            .keyBy(0)
            .timeWindow(Time.seconds(5))
            .apply(new MyWindowFunction())
            .sum(1)
            .filter(word -> word.f1 >= 3);
```

I would like to create a WindowFunction to sort the output by the value of words found. The WindowFunction that I am trying to implement does not compile at all. I am struggling to define the apply method and the parameters of the WindowFunction interface.

```
public static class MyWindowFunction implements WindowFunction<
        Tuple2<String, Integer>, // input type
        Tuple2<String, Integer>, // output type
        Tuple2<String, Integer>, // key type
        TimeWindow> {

    void apply(Tuple2<String, Integer> key, TimeWindow window, Iterable<Tuple2<String, Integer>> input, Collector<Tuple2<String, Integer>> out) {

        String word = ((Tuple2<String, Integer>)key).f0;
        Integer count = ((Tuple2<String, Integer>)key).f1;

        .........
        out.collect(new Tuple2<>(word, count));
    }
}
```

Comment: The ConnectedCarEvent example you mention is solving a very different problem: it is sorting an event-time stream so that it is in order by timestamp. Also, it's not a global sort, but key-by-key.

Comment: Yes, you could implement a WindowFunction that sorts the window's contents.

Comment: Hi David. thanks for your reply. I've read about WindowFunction but I am struggling to implement. Could you help me, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am updating this answer to use Flink 1.12.0. In order to sort the elements of a stream in I had to use a `KeyedProcessFunction` after counting the stream with a `ReduceFunction`. Then I had to set the parallelism of the very last transformation to `1` in order to not change the order of the elements that I sorted using `KeyedProcessFunction`. The sequence that I am using is `socketTextStream` -> `flatMap` -> `keyBy` -> `reduce` -> `keyBy` -> `process` -> `print().setParallelism(1)`. Bellow it the example:

```
public class SocketWindowWordCountJava {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        env.socketTextStream("localhost", 9000)
                .flatMap(new SplitterFlatMap())
                .keyBy(new WordKeySelector())
                .reduce(new SumReducer())
                .keyBy(new WordKeySelector())
                .process(new SortKeyedProcessFunction(3 * 1000))
                .print().setParallelism(1);
        String executionPlan = env.getExecutionPlan();
        System.out.println("ExecutionPlan ........................ ");
        System.out.println(executionPlan);
        System.out.println("........................ ");
        env.execute("Window WordCount sorted");
    }
}
```

The UDF that I used to sort the stream is the `SortKeyedProcessFunction` which extends `KeyedProcessFunction`. I use a `ValueState<List<Event>> listState` of `Event implements Comparable<Event>` to have a sorted list as state. On the `processElement` method I register the time stamp that I added the event to the state `context.timerService().registerProcessingTimeTimer(timeoutTime);` and I collect the event at the `onTimer` method. I am also using a time window of 3 seconds here.

```
public class SortKeyedProcessFunction extends KeyedProcessFunction<String, Tuple2<String, Integer>, Event> {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 7289761960983988878L;
        // delay after which an alert flag is thrown
        private final long timeOut;
        // state to remember the last timer set
        private ValueState<List<Event>> listState = null;
        private ValueState<Long> lastTime = null;

        public SortKeyedProcessFunction(long timeOut) {
            this.timeOut = timeOut;
        }

        @Override
        public void open(Configuration conf) {
            // setup timer and HLL state
            ValueStateDescriptor<List<Event>> descriptor = new ValueStateDescriptor<>(
                    // state name
                    "sorted-events",
                    // type information of state
                    TypeInformation.of(new TypeHint<List<Event>>() {
                    }));
            listState = getRuntimeContext().getState(descriptor);

            ValueStateDescriptor<Long> descriptorLastTime = new ValueStateDescriptor<Long>(
                    "lastTime",
                    TypeInformation.of(new TypeHint<Long>() {
                    }));

            lastTime = getRuntimeContext().getState(descriptorLastTime);
        }

        @Override
        public void processElement(Tuple2<String, Integer> value, Context context, Collector<Event> collector) throws Exception {
            // get current time and compute timeout time
            long currentTime = context.timerService().currentProcessingTime();
            long timeoutTime = currentTime + timeOut;
            // register timer for timeout time
            context.timerService().registerProcessingTimeTimer(timeoutTime);

            List<Event> queue = listState.value();
            if (queue == null) {
                queue = new ArrayList<Event>();
            }
            Long current = lastTime.value();
            queue.add(new Event(value.f0, value.f1));
            lastTime.update(timeoutTime);
            listState.update(queue);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTimer(long timestamp, OnTimerContext ctx, Collector<Event> out) throws Exception {
            // System.out.println("onTimer: " + timestamp);
            // check if this was the last timer we registered
            System.out.println("timestamp: " + timestamp);
            List<Event> queue = listState.value();
            Long current = lastTime.value();

            if (timestamp == current.longValue()) {
                Collections.sort(queue);

                queue.forEach( e -> {
                    out.collect(e);
                });
                queue.clear();
                listState.clear();
            }
        }
    }

class Event implements Comparable<Event> {
    String value;
    Integer qtd;
    public Event(String value, Integer qtd) {
        this.value = value;
        this.qtd = qtd;
    }
    public String getValue() { return value; }
    public Integer getQtd() { return qtd; }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Event{" +"value='" + value + '\'' +", qtd=" + qtd +'}';
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(@NotNull Event event) {
        return this.getValue().compareTo(event.getValue());
    }
}
```

So when I use `$ nc -lk 9000` and type the words on the console I see them in order on the output

```
...
Event{value='soccer', qtd=7}
Event{value='swim', qtd=5}

...
Event{value='basketball', qtd=9}
Event{value='soccer', qtd=8}
Event{value='swim', qtd=6}
```

The other UDFs are for the other transformations of the stream program and they are here for completeness.

```
public class SplitterFlatMap implements FlatMapFunction<String, Tuple2<String, Integer>> {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 3121588720675797629L;
        @Override
        public void flatMap(String sentence, Collector<Tuple2<String, Integer>> out) throws Exception {
            for (String word : sentence.split(" ")) {
                out.collect(Tuple2.of(word, 1));
            }
        }
    }
    public class WordKeySelector implements KeySelector<Tuple2<String, Integer>, String> {
        @Override
        public String getKey(Tuple2<String, Integer> value) throws Exception {
            return value.f0;
        }
    }
    public class SumReducer implements ReduceFunction<Tuple2<String, Integer>> {
        @Override
        public Tuple2<String, Integer> reduce(Tuple2<String, Integer> event1, Tuple2<String, Integer> event2) throws Exception {
            return Tuple2.of(event1.f0, event1.f1 + event2.f1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: How does this sort the results?

Comment: I am updating my project to the latest version of Flink and I will get back to edit this answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `.sum(1)` method will do everything you need (no need for using `apply()`), as long as the `Splitter` class (which should be a `FlatMapFunction`) is emitting `Tuple2<String, Integer>` records, where `String` is the word, and `Integer` is always `1`.

So then `.sum(1)` will do the aggregation for you. If you needed something different than what `sum()` does, you would typically use `.reduce(new MyCustomReduceFunction())`, as that's going to be the most efficient and scalable approach, in terms of not needing to buffer lots in memory.

Comment: yes @kkrugler, I know that the `sum(1)` does sum up everything. I am trying to enhance the example by implementing `MyWindowFunction` to sort the output. To print it in a fancy way. The result will not change at all. I just want to practice some `WindowFunction`.